# CMake dependency for Rust project fails to build on Windows when paths are longer than 260 characters

Tags: windows, rust, cmake, glfw

**Edit** - due to the nature of this issue, I've decided to file this as a [bug report on the cmake-rs repository](https://github.com/rust-lang/cmake-rs/issues/168). I'll leave this question up as well just in case any CMake Wizards stumble on this and know the answer to getting CMake to work with long paths.

---

I'm trying to use the [GLFW](https://crates.io/crates/glfw) crate with Rust to work with OpenGL. By default, this crate runs CMake as part of a build script to compile GLFW, which is the desired behaviour.

After installing CMake (version 3.25.0) and putting it on my PATH, I followed [the guide on GLFW's site](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/quick.html) combined with [LearnOpenGL](https://learnopengl.com/Getting-started/Hello-Triangle) to get a window up and running, and it works totally fine:

[image: GLFW window running beside Cargo's compiler build logs, displaying a multi-colored triangle. The working directory is ~/Desktop/opengl-test.]

(The code for this example is available as a [GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/matthew-e-brown/7b727593ec9d33f058c9b97aa76566a6), if you wish to see it)

"Excellent," I thought to myself, "now I'm ready to start the final project for my Computer Graphics course" (we've been using WebGL all semester, I figured I should try real OpenGL). However, when I duplicate the project into a different folder, everything breaks:

[image: The working project is copied to ~/Dropbox/Coursework/5th Year - 2022-2023/Fall/COIS-4480H Computer Graphics/FinalProject, and the same command, 'rm -rf target && cargo run' is ran. This time, a giant error message.]

The full output is as follows:

```
   Compiling cfg-if v1.0.0
   Compiling khronos_api v3.1.0
   Compiling winapi v0.3.9
   Compiling log v0.4.17
   Compiling cc v1.0.76
   Compiling xml-rs v0.8.4
   Compiling windows_x86_64_msvc v0.42.0
   Compiling time-core v0.1.0
   Compiling time-macros v0.2.6
   Compiling itoa v1.0.4
   Compiling cty v0.2.2
   Compiling cmake v0.1.49
   Compiling gl_generator v0.14.0
   Compiling lazy_static v1.4.0
   Compiling raw-window-handle v0.4.3
   Compiling windows-sys v0.42.0
   Compiling bitflags v1.3.2
   Compiling time v0.3.17
   Compiling gl v0.14.0
   Compiling glfw-sys v4.0.0+3.3.5
   Compiling atty v0.2.14
   Compiling colored v2.0.0
   Compiling simple_logger v4.0.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `glfw-sys v4.0.0+3.3.5`

Caused by:
  process didn't exit successfully: `C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-e2e03b0e00e0d338\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
  --- stdout
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_GENERATOR = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH = None
  CMAKE_x86_64-pc-windows-msvc = None
  CMAKE_x86_64_pc_windows_msvc = None
  HOST_CMAKE = None
  CMAKE = None
  running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\Matthew\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\glfw-sys-4.0.0+3.3.5\\." "-G" "Visual Studio 17 2022" "-Thost=x64" "-Ax64" "-DGLFW_BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF" "-DGLFW_BUILD_TESTS=OFF" "-DGLFW_BUILD_DOCS=OFF" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=lib" "-DGLFW_BUILD_WAYLAND=ON" "-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=C:\\Users\\Matthew\\Dropbox\\Coursework\\5th Year - 2022-2023\\Fall\\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\\FinalProject\\target\\debug\\build\\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_ASM_FLAGS_DEBUG= -nologo -MD -Brepro" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug"
  -- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.19041.0 to target Windows 10.0.19045.
  -- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.33.31630.0
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe
  -- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe - broken
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
  See also "C:/Users/Matthew/Dropbox/Coursework/5th Year - 2022-2023/Fall/COIS-4480H Computer Graphics/FinalProject/target/debug/build/glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c/out/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
  See also "C:/Users/Matthew/Dropbox/Coursework/5th Year - 2022-2023/Fall/COIS-4480H Computer Graphics/FinalProject/target/debug/build/glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c/out/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

  --- stderr
  CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.25/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:70 (message):
    The C compiler

      "C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.33.31629/bin/Hostx64/x64/cl.exe"

    is not able to compile a simple test program.

    It fails with the following output:

      Change Dir: C:/Users/Matthew/Dropbox/Coursework/5th Year - 2022-2023/Fall/COIS-4480H Computer Graphics/FinalProject/target/debug/build/glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c/out/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeScratch/TryCompile-4wccup

      Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2022/BuildTools/MSBuild/Current/Bin/amd64/MSBuild.exe cmTC_187a6.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=17.0 /v:m && MSBuild version 17.3.1+2badb37d1 for .NET Framework
        testCCompiler.c
      FileTracker : error FTK1011: could not create the new file tracking log file: C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.dir\Debug\cmTC_187a6.tlog\link-cvtres.read.1.tlog. The system cannot find the path specified. [C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.vcxproj]



      FileTracker : error FTK1011: could not create the new file tracking log file: C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.dir\Debug\cmTC_187a6.tlog\link-cvtres.write.1.tlog. The system cannot find the path specified. [C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.vcxproj]








    CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    CMakeLists.txt:3 (project)


  thread 'main' panicked at '
  command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

  build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\Matthew\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.49\src\lib.rs:1104:5
  note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

The key parts seem to be the following lines:

```
FileTracker : error FTK1011: could not create the new file tracking log file: C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.dir\Debug\cmTC_187a6.tlog\link-cvtres.read.1.tlog. The system cannot find the path specified. [C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.vcxproj]
```

```
FileTracker : error FTK1011: could not create the new file tracking log file: C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.dir\Debug\cmTC_187a6.tlog\link-cvtres.write.1.tlog. The system cannot find the path specified. [C:\Users\Matthew\Dropbox\Coursework\5th Year - 2022-2023\Fall\COIS-4480H Computer Graphics\FinalProject\target\debug\build\glfw-sys-9e8b97620887df2c\out\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeScratch\TryCompile-4wccup\cmTC_187a6.vcxproj]
```

This error code, `FTK1011`, doesn't really come up a whole lot when Googling, so I'm at a bit of a loss. I checked the given path, and I can confirm it doesn't exist; `CMakeScratch` is an empty folder. Though, if it's a "scratch" folder, that might be because it's being cleared after the process exits.

[Here's a full screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBEKf.png) of the `target/debug/build`'s `glfw-sys-*` directories. If you would like to see any other log files let me know and I'll add them to the question. [Here are the two files it says to "see also"](https://gist.github.com/matthew-e-brown/73035d381d06ad4c46f009a62e36b45b), `CMakeError.log` and `CMakeOutput.log`.

Currently, my best guess is that my folder for COIS-4480H Computer Graphics has too long of a path—one which I obviously don't want to change, since it fits so nicely with the rest of my university work's organizational structure. This is supported by the other locations I've tried: it works both in `~/Dropbox/Code/Tests/rust-opengl-test` (so it's not Dropbox), as well as `~/Desktop/Some Folder/opengl` (so it's not the spaces). I tried running with `CMAKE_USE_RELATIVE_PATHS` set to `TRUE` as a last-ditch effort, but to no avail.

I've never user CMake outside of this, so I have no idea where to go from here as far as troubleshooting goes.

Comment: How did you "duplicate the project into a different folder"? If you simply copied the folder, try removing the `build` folder and recompiling.

Comment: @Jmb If you take a close look at the top of the second screenshot, you'll see the commands I ran. I built it each time after removing the build folder: `rm -rf target && cargo run`. Unless there's a different `build` folder that you're referring to?

Comment: That is a limitation of the Visual Studio toolchain. IIRC the compiler can handle long paths, but the linker cannot. So if you try to link a shared library or an executable (in this case CMake tries to test that the toolchain works by compiling and linking a test executable) then the path of the object files musn't be longer than 260 characters. You can work around this by mounting the directory as a drive with the `subst` command and building from there.